# Unable to package Appcelerator android module

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules, titanium-android

Created sample mobile module app with 8.3.1.GA Ti SDK.
Tried to package the module.

```
Expected:
Module should be packaged without any errors.
```

Actual:

Throwing the below error

> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.008Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms
>   /Users/pc270889/.appcelerator/install/7.1.2/package/appc.js
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.078Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 67ms
>   /Users/pc270889/.appcelerator/install/7.1.2/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/appc.js
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.078Z | DEBUG  | run plugin:
>   /Users/pc270889/.appcelerator/install/7.1.2/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.081Z | DEBUG  | [PLUGIN-LOAD] 1ms
>   /Users/pc270889/.appcelerator/install/7.1.2/package/node_modules/arrow/appc.js
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.108Z | DEBUG  | run plugin:
>   /Users/pc270889/.appcelerator/install/7.1.2/package/node_modules/arrow
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.137Z | TRACE  | plugin "arrow" failed its "when"
>   function check, skipping...
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.138Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for
>   command "run" CLI options via function
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.139Z | TRACE  | loading plugin "titanium" for
>   command "run" CLI options via array
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.141Z | TRACE  | executing command "run" with the
>   following plugins:
>
> ["titanium"]
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.143Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in
>   opts.session
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:28.144Z | DEBUG  | Titanium Downloads Last Checked:
>   1586240964935
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:29.078Z | TRACE  | getInstalledTiSdkInfo {
>
> sdkPath: '/Users/pc270889/Library/Application Support/Titanium',
>
> activeSDK: '8.3.1.GA'
>
> }
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:29.078Z | DEBUG  | active sdk info {
>
> sdkPath: '/Users/pc270889/Library/Application Support/Titanium',
>
> activeSDK: '8.3.1.GA'
>
> }
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:32.902Z | DEBUG  | to download
>   {"modules":[{"id":"hyperloop","name":"Hyperloop","description":"Gain
>   complete access to native APIs in your Titanium mobile
>   applications.","guid":"99a136cd-4e51-40da-bcdb-d514f5895fb5","version":"1.2.8","url":"https://downloads.platform.axway.com/modules/hyperloop-1.2.8.zip","min_mobilesdk_version":"5.4.0","oses":["linux","win32","osx"],"platforms":["iphone","android"],"required":true,"partner":null,"versions":[{"platforms":["iphone","android","windows"],"sdk_versions":">=6.0.0
>   <7.0.0","version":"2.2.3","url":"https://downloads.platform.axway.com/modules/hyperloop-2.2.3.zip"}]},{"id":"ti.cloudpush","name":"ti.cloudpush","description":"Enables
>   Mobile Backend Services Push Notifications for Android
>   applications.","guid":"2d542783-c83c-4597-bd61-1073aa16ece2","oses":["linux","win32","osx"],"platforms":["android"],"required":true,"partner":null,"versions":[{"platforms":["android"],"sdk_versions":">=7.5.0
>   <8.0.0","version":"6.0.0","url":"https://downloads.platform.axway.com/modules/ti.cloudpush-android-6.0.0.zip"},{"platforms":["android"],"sdk_versions":">=7.0.0
>   <7.5.0","version":"5.2.1","url":"https://downloads.platform.axway.com/modules/ti.cloudpush-android-5.2.1.zip"}]},{"id":"com.appcelerator.aca","name":"Appcelerator
>   Crash Analytics","description":"Enables Appcelerator Crash Analytics.
>   Appcelerator Crash Analytics allows you to identify and troubleshoot
>   crashes in your mobile
>   applications.","guid":"ec713280-46fb-46ad-b9af-4435dfca143b","oses":["linux","win32","osx"],"platforms":["iphone","android"],"required":true,"partner":"aca","download":true,"versions":[{"platforms":["iphone","android"],"sdk_versions":">=9.0.0","version":"2.0.0","url":"https://downloads.platform.axway.com/modules/com.appcelerator.aca-2.0.0.zip"},{"platforms":["iphone","android"],"sdk_versions":">=8.1.1 <9.0.0","version":"1.4.3","url":"https://downloads.platform.axway.com/modules/com.appcelerator.aca-1.4.3.zip"},{"platforms":["iphone","android"],"sdk_versions":">=8.0.0 <8.1.1","version":"1.3.0","url":"https://downloads.platform.axway.com/modules/com.appcelerator.aca-1.3.0.zip"}]}],"components":[]}
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:32.907Z | DEBUG  | Module Found com.appcelerator.aca
>   iphone 1.4.3
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:32.907Z | DEBUG  | Module Found com.appcelerator.aca
>   android 1.4.3
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:32.908Z | DEBUG  | com.appcelerator.aca iphone Latest
>   Version 1.4.3
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:32.908Z | DEBUG  | com.appcelerator.aca android
>   Latest Version 1.4.3
>
> 2020-04-07T07:14:32.940Z | TRACE  | No project alloy hook; skipping
>   update to 1.0.1
>
> 4/7/2020, 12:44:34 PM

**Operating System**

```
Name                        = Mac OS X

  Version                     = 10.14.6

  Architecture                = 64bit

  # CPUs                      = 8

  Memory                      = 17179869184

Node.js

  Node.js Version             = 12.14.0

  npm Version                 = 6.13.4

Titanium CLI

  CLI Version                 = 5.2.2

Titanium SDK

  SDK Version                 = 8.3.1.GA

  SDK Path                    = /Users/pc270889/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/8.3.1.GA

  Target Platform             = android
```

**Command**

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/pc270889/.appcelerator/install/7.1.2/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js build --platform android --project-dir /Users/pc270889/Documents/Arun/kofaxModuleWorkspace/samplemodule/android --build-only --log-level trace --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt --no-banner --prompt-type socket-bundle --prompt-port 49898 --config-file /var/folders/wj/xt_k91vj6xb8g84bj4lswjtc0000gn/T/build-1586243668144.json --no-banner --project-dir /Users/pc270889/Documents/Arun/kofaxModuleWorkspace/samplemodule/android

Update the android:minSdkVersion in the tiapp.xml or custom AndroidManifest to at least 19:
```

> [ERROR] :  The minimum supported SDK API version must be 19 or newer,
>   but is currently set to 16
>
> ```
> <android>
>
>     <manifest>
>
>         <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
>
>     </manifest>
>
> </android>
> ```

Comment: I'm a bit confused where which error appears. So the module is building fine and you compile it with `appc ti build -p android --build-only` ? Is the `<android>` section from your module or your app? The 8.3.1 default min is already 19 (https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/8_3_X/android/titanium/AndroidManifest.xml#L7) so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Able to package module successfully. It is picking the other project android manifest file. So created a different workspace in different root folder where there was no appcelerator projects.